# Which class is needed to specify encodeByte() method?

Tags: java, csv, base64, hbase

I want to import my data from a csv file to hbase in java.  But I can't find the encodeByte method  in the Base64 class.  In the below line:

```
Base64.encodeByte(actualSeparator.getBytes())
```

I get an error.

Can you tell me which class needs to be imported or which file jar I need to inset in my library?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to encode one byte but are passing a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Apache-Commons Base64 Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) is really easy:

> import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

and using this line of code:

> byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(actualSeparator.getBytes());

[Main page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) of project and [download page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi)